# Regex RightToLeft '\w' matching different from default

Tags: .net, regex

I am confused why .NET `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` causes the `\w` and `\W` tokens to behave differently.

For example, using the regex `(\d{1,7})\w?` with the input `500` produces two different captures for the first group with `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` on or off. With it on, the result is `50`, with it off it's `500`. With the regex `(\d{1,7})\s?` you get `500` in either case. Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the order or greediness I'm sure.  When you match from right to left `\w?` becomes the first part and is greedy to match a `0`, leaving only `50` for the `\d` to match.  Going left to right `\d{1,7}` is greedy and matches all 3 digits, leaving nothing for `\w` but that's OK because of the `?`.  0 is not a space though, so the `\s` match is unaffected by this.

Comment: Clearly I was misunderstanding, and embarrassingly so. I had it in my head that `\w` didn't match digits :(